# What ports should I filter on a default Magento installation

Tags: ports, iptables, filtering

I have recently installed a Magento on Ubuntu 14.04 on Digital Ocean and I'm wondering what ports should I filter to keep it safe. Well, actually the question should be: what ports I keep open to the internet?

A list of ports, identified with they should be `inbound` or `outbound`, would be enough. A better answer would be a list of `iptables` commands to secure the server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I am going to assume that your server *does nothing except ecommerce*. Therefore, the only ports you need are:

80 - Default HTTP, so that you can accept connections and redirect to...
443 - SSL / TLS for secure transactions.
SSH, but... it's better to choose a high random port instead of the standard 22.

**Put SSH on a high random port**

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change the *port* directive to a high random port. You can manually choose an "Unassigned" port from the IANA list of ports, or, you can be lazy and [use a script I wrote](https://github.com/mjmunger/random-high-port) that downloads the current port list, finds the unassigned ports, and randomly picks one for you.

This doesn't necessarily "increase security," but lowers the number of probes that are looking for low hanging fruit on 22.

For the sake of argument, let's say you have chosen **32637** as the port. This is important in the latter part of the answer.

**Configure iptables**

Firstly, we need to do this as a script so that it can be completed at once.

Here's a [gist for you to lock down the server](https://gist.github.com/mjmunger/0ee176b88ce403d743bfad6129878f37). But the code is also below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Default deny
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#Allow established sessions
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#Allow tcp/80 (HTTP)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow tcp/443 (HTTPS)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow SSH on our random port
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32637  -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Here's how it works:

1. We start by default blocking everything from everywhere. Since you are running eCommerce and only need 80 and 443, we default block everything else.
2. Next we allow established sessions to remain active and work. This is so we don't disconnect ourselves during the process. But it's also useful for sessions that will be established later to remain established.
3. Next, we allow localhost. I assume you're talking to a DB server (MySQL?) for Magento.
4. The last three rules explicitly allow 80, 443, and 32637, which are HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH on our high random port configured above.

And, of course, if you want to reset iptables, here you go:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**inbound or outbound**

Everything above is inbound.

Regarding outbound blocking: here, we are assuming that your server is not compromised, will need to send email confirmations, and is otherwise well maintained. There is *no* outbound blocking. If your server is clean and well run, there's really no reason to do that.

Unless you have a reason... but a default Magento (web application installation) that is properly maintained and secured doesn't really need it because it should not be sending out rouge connections, scans, or requests.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, SSH should not be configured to allow user / pass authentication for root (or any user in my opinion). Only SSH key authentication.